# libGDX make camera move faster upwards depends on time

Tags: android, camera, libgdx

I try to make a game, where camera will move upwards (with growing speed) and player must jump higher. If hi will slower then camera - game over.
 
Question: how to make a movement of the camera faster?
 Now I have a constant movement, but need accelerated:

```
private void cameraMovement(){
    float speed=1;  
    camera.position.y = camera.position.y + speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing speed from local to field and adding some value in `cameraMovement()` should do it

```
private float speed = 1;
private float acc   = 0.5f;
private void cameraMovement(){
    speed += acc;  
    camera.position.y = camera.position.y + speed;
}
```

I think you would want this speed the same in all devices so I would multiply by delta

```
private float speed = 1;
private float acc   = 10f; // note that here the value is greater
private void cameraMovement(){
    speed += acc * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();  
    camera.position.y = camera.position.y + speed;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details ? Thank you

Comment: That`s it! Thank you!